# Trouble understanding a LIKE operator syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sql-like, coalesce

I got pasted a source code to extract a particular dataset and I am having a problem understanding one of the bits. Here's the part of a query:

```
WHERE r LIKE 
((COALESCE(ur.title, '') || ' ' || COALESCE(urd.reviewtext, '')) ,'.* coronavirus .*|.* SARS .*', 'si')
```

Could you help me translate what does the inside bracket of this `LIKE` operator mean? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: MySQL or Postgres?

Comment: So this comes from my boss, I'm not sure where did he type this query but I'm pretty sure it's either PostgreSQL or Snowflake

Comment: Why don't you ask the boss for clarification? Are you afraid?

Comment: I'm asking right now, but I work remotely, he's London based and I'm in Singapore so there's a delay. haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COALESCE` takes second argument if first one is `NULL`.

So let me got through couple of possibilities:

- `ur.title` is `NULL`, `urd.reviewtext` is `'review`, then `(COALESCE(ur.title, '') || ' ' || COALESCE(urd.reviewtext, ''))` evaluates to: `review ,`
- if both are `NULL` then `((COALESCE(ur.title, '') || ' ' || COALESCE(urd.reviewtext, ''))` evaluates to '  ,'
- `ur.title` is `title`, `urd.reviewtext` is `'review`, then `(COALESCE(ur.title, '') || ' ' || COALESCE(urd.reviewtext, ''))` evaluates to: `title review ,`

Now, after `(COALESCE(ur.title, '') || ' ' || COALESCE(urd.reviewtext, ''))(COALESCE(ur.title, '') || ' ' || COALESCE(urd.reviewtext, ''))` there's no concatenation operator, so it's hard to guess what's going on here, it's syntax error.

It looks like you want to compare against multiple values, but it doesn't work like that. You should write something like:

```
LIKE (COALESCE(ur.title, '') || ' ' || COALESCE(urd.reviewtext, '')) OR
LIKE '.* coronavirus .*|.* SARS .*' OR
LIKE 'si'
```

In first, as I broke down, doesn't have any wildcards or any regex specific parts, so it compares literally. Same holds for last clause `si`, so it will match only `si` literally.

In second clause `'.* coronavirus .*|.* SARS .*'`, there are regular expression specific parts as `.*`, but it isn't suppoerted in SQL regex. It means generally match zero or more of any characters. You got also `|` there which is alterantion. But, again, it won't work as SQL doesn't suppoert full regex.

**EDIT:** it looks like Postgre operator `SIMILAIR TO` supports above regex.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed and constructive response! Yes I understand the first bit of the usage of COALESCE and double vertical bar to concat. And yet still a mystery to me what is he trying to find from that specification. Basically I am trying to find out of any reviews in the database have mentioned coronavirus in it. So, I'm guessing '.* coronavirus .*|.* SARS .*' means either the review has any of those words. But yeah, I'm still perplexed. Thanks again!

Comment: @pascahasanudin Best would be just use `columnName LIKE '%coronavirus%' OR columnName LIKE '%SARS%'` , `%` means any number of any character :) You could use even `LOCATE` function (if it is MySQL), it will return index of searched string, if it's not found, it will return -1 (in postgre it's `strpos`). If my answer helped you, you should accept it and optionally upvote ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE r LIKE 
((COALESCE(ur.title, '') || ' ' || COALESCE(urd.reviewtext, '')) ,'.* coronavirus .*|.* SARS .*', 'si')

1. COALESCE(ur.title, '') - coalesce function to give first not null value.
2. || ' ' || - to concat space with CONCAT function output.
3. COALESCE(urd.reviewtext, '') - coalesce function to give first not null value.
```

Answer (score 0):

The COALESCE function in SQL is used when there is a possibility on the column return a null value. The Function change the null to a desired substitute. Ex: COALESCE(title, '') => will change any null data to ''.

In that particular case is not working because the LIKE function is being used on many columns. You need a => WHERE x LIKE y or x LIKE z

Answer (score -1):

> WHERE r LIKE ((COALESCE(ur.title, '') || ' ' || COALESCE(urd.reviewtext, '')) ,'.* coronavirus .*|.* SARS .*', 'si')

```
WHERE r LIKE ( ( COALESCE(ur.title, '') || ' ' || COALESCE(urd.reviewtext, '')
               ) ,
               '.* coronavirus .*|.* SARS .*',
               'si'
             )
```

Syntax error guaranteed in both MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answe such that others can learn from it

Comment: @NicoHaase ??? do you want me to copy a lot of pages from user manuals? This text is synthactically incorrect. In both DBMS. If somebody want to understand what is the incorrectness REALLY he would create minimal tables structure and ask SQL server to build execution plan - server will say what is wrong. For example, none DBMS allows to use 3-part structure as an argument of LIKE operator...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Syntax error guaranteed" - how does this help anybody to understand how your answer solves the (maybe unclear?) problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase Understand only what is written, do not try to add something or find some hidden meaning in these words. I guarantee that when using this construct, you will get a syntax error message - that's all, and nothing more. Keep it simple...

Comment: So,how does posting a "construct" that produces a syntax error help the OP to understand the problem? Why not provide a solution that **explains** what is wrong and how to solve it?

Comment: @NicoHaase I can predict the way which the code was produced by. But I cannot predice the goal of this transformation. Especially I can't predict the ultimate goal. You think it's better to save SO some kbyted and not post at all? Maybe you're right. But I did not decide to correct the original question and format the code in it so that its structure (and its irregularity) was visible - and the code is not formatted in the comment.

Comment: No, I haven't said that any bytes should be saved. It's fine to highlight an error, but then please do so. Without telling the OP what he made wrong, it's pretty hard to improve.

Comment: @NicoHaase *It's fine to highlight an error* It is **impossibe** to highlight an error **in this case**. It looks like "to highlight excess space char". The only variant is to highlight the whole code - but what's the point? Are you against such comments written in response format because they can't be written in comment format? You may be right. But I think a bad answer is better than no answer.